# std::threads not available in windows forms

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback, windows-forms-designer, timed

I have this callable timer, but the std::threads are not not available when working with Windows forms

```
class Timer
{
public:
    template <class callable, class... arguments>
    Timer(int after, bool async, callable&& f, arguments&&... args)
    {
        std::function<typename std::result_of<callable(arguments...)>::type()> task(std::bind(std::forward<callable>(f), std::forward<arguments>(args)...));

        if (async)
        {
            std::thread([after, task]() {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(after));
                task();
            }).detach();
        }
        else
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(after));
            task();
        }
    }

};
```

Any one have an alternative to it?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Did you include the `<thread>` header and does your compiler support the C++11 standard?

Comment: Using visual studios 2017 compiler

Comment: Error (active) E0035 #error directive: <thread> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure

Answer (score 0):

Bysetting the timer and the cpp file using it to be unmanaged, i was able to use this timer anyway. [more about that here](http://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2013/10/17/can-i-use-stdthread-from-a-ccli-project-in-visual-studio-2012/)